# I am having troubles with learning how to use STR and INT and ELIF

Tags: python

```
age = str(input("how old are you?"))
if age >= 18:
  print("have a beer")
elif age == 17:
  print("have a car")
elif age == 16: 
  print("have a book")
else: print("go away")
```

the error that pops up says
Typeerror: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str't 'int'
i am starting this for school and i am confused, my teacher just left us and i dont know what to do.
do i change the >= to a > or do i change the str to and int?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `int` (or to numeric type in general) in order to do numeric comparisons later, such as `>=`:

```
age = int(input("how old are you?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that you're trying to compare a **string** with a **number** in a way that is not valid `>=`.

`str` converts the input to a string.

`int` converts the input, where possible, to an integer.

So, **yes, please**, change `str` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Note

```
age = str(input("how old are you?"))
```

that this is redundant, as [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) itself returns string

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
> without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
> converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
> that.

i.e. this give same effect as writing

```
age = input("how old are you?")
```